# Configure mail.rb for localhost testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, restful-authentication, activation

is it possible to configure mail.rb (in RESTFUL authentication) to test email activation locally? the default file is

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "mail.example-domain.com",
    :port => 25,
    :domain => "www.example-domain.com",
    :authentication => :login,
    :user_name => "user@example-domain.com",
    :password => "secret"
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:

- http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/HowToSendEmailsWithActionMailer

Just make a yaml file with all the config

Comment: thanx. i used this http://avnetlabs.com/rails/restful-authentication-with-rails-2 actually. but it's just like what you said.

Answer (score 0):

I really like using [MailTrap](http://rubymatt.rubyforge.org/mailtrap/) -- a local SMTP server that knows Just Enough about SMTP to listen to ActionMailer requests... and write them to a file where you can look at them later.